# Making Dendrogram Bins Thicker in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I have a linkage matrix of about size 10,000 that I've plotted using `scipy.cluster.hierarchical`. The default rendering is poor -- as expected, given the size of the input -- because the bins are way too narrow to discern any meaningful structure in the dendrogram. How can I force the bins to be further apart so I can see the data better? I realize this will require the image to be *huge*, but that's OK.

I'm aware of `dendrogram`'s truncate functionality. I will likely end up using it, but I'd like to get a look at the full data in a presentation I can grok visually before I start truncating.

Here's the rendering as it appears now. Increasing the image size using `figsize` does not appear to help, nor does `xtick.major.pad`.

```
fig = pylab.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
Z = sch.dendrogram(Y, leaf_rotation=90)
fig.show()
fig.savefig('dendrogram.jpg')
```

[image: the rendering]

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Not a direct answer, but: matplotlib is limited in capabilities. Take a look at `R ggplot`  or the `OpenGL` graphics libraries, for example.

Comment: Appreciate the pointer! I'm totally willing to switch to ggplot. Can you point me to some code that would let me visualize large dendrograms in the way I described above?

Comment: Well..It kinda looks to me like a bar plot, which is easily achieved. You could start with the documentation listed on the `ggplot` page at CRAN.  It also occurs to me that you might want to bin your data down to a managable size of a couple hundred or so; then create a second "zoomed" plot of any subregion of interest.  It really depends on what you're trying to tell the reader.